# Vertical alignment on mobile devices

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I'm having trouble vertically aligning an SVG on mobile devices. I've tested on an iPhone 5s, 6s and iPad Air 2. It seems to work perfectly on Chrome Responsive Mode but not on an actual mobile browser. I can't confirm if it's working on Android as I don't have one.

http://accoutrements.studio/

Here's how it's looking on my iPhone – https://i.stack.imgur.com/87qiM.png

It should be vertically and horizontally aligned in the centre of the page. It's displaying slightly off centre (vertically) on iOS Safari. Is there anything I can change in the code or is this a Safari bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svg is being positioned by margin-top: 50vh. Try this instead:

```
.accoutrements {
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I've had a chance to test my original code on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge and it's working fine. It must be an iOS Safari issue! Thanks.

Comment: iOS safari does have issues with vh units but you can center across devices and browsers. You'll need to use top: 50% which is already in your code if you dont want to use flexbox. 

It looks like there may be other lines in your code causing unexpected behaviors across scenarios. 

From what I can see in devtools I would:
remove position: relative and your media position: inherit, left: 10%, display: block. Add margin: auto and display: block for svg.logo not just in your media.

You may also want to remove the default margins on the body to prevent overflow.